# Passing ref class member function as a parameter

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm attempting to create a wrapper allowing System::Task objects to be created in a one liner. So far I have the following working -

```
ref class TaskRunner abstract sealed
{
public:
    generic<typename TArg0>
    static Task^ Create(Action<TArg0>^ f, TArg0 arg0) {
        return Task::Run((gcnew BindAction1<TArg0>(f, arg0))->binder);
    }
private:
    generic<typename TArg0>
    ref class BindAction1
    {
        initonly TArg0 _arg0;
        Action<TArg0>^ const f;
        void _() { return f(_arg0); }
    public:
        initonly Action^ binder;
        BindAction1(Action<TArg0>^ f, TArg0 arg0) : f(f), _arg0(arg0) {
            binder = gcnew Action(this, &BindAction1::_);
        }
    };
}
```

Which can be called via -

```
auto task = TaskRunner::Create(gcnew Action<TArg0>(this, &Class::Function), arg0);
```

However i'd like to remove the need to create the action manually. I.e. modify Create so the call looks like-

```
auto task = TaskRunner::Create(this, &Class::Function, arg0);
```

and call gcnew Action(obj, func) inside of Create. I don't know if this is possible. If so how would I declare the arguments for create?

Effectively they need to be the same as the Action delegate. Looking at the system library Action seems to take a System::Object and System::IntPtr but i can't get it to work using those as arguments.

*Update - Thanks IllidanS4 for the complete answer and your help in getting this working. For anyone attempting to use the code in his answer there appears to be a compiler bug in Visual Studio 2015 which requires the delegate_type to be overridden for each argument chain length.

Comment: Having a method name automagically converted into a delegate is a feature of the C# language.  But not of C++/CLI, it eschews syntax sugar like that.  Not unlike C++.  But mixing languages certainly is a .net feature, there is no obvious reason why this code could not be written in C#, given that it doesn't do any kind of native interop.

Comment: @HansPassant - this is a wrapper library around a native library which needs to be callable by C# or C++CLI. I.e. the tasks being returned include calls to native. Unless there is a way to mix C# and C++ within a file the only way I know to do what you suggest is a separate C# library around the C++CLI one - which isn't really ideal.

Comment: Please also include the relevant overloads of `TaskRunner::Create` and your usage of `CreateTask2`. I get some errors if I specify `"string"` instead of `gcnew String("string")` but nothing else.

Comment: @IllidanS4 - Added.

Comment: It's weird I get similar errors in Visual Studio even when creating normal delegate directly in IntelliSense, but I get it to compile. Maybe you have some old version of the compiler, or are running into some weird bug. No surprise considering Microsoft doesn't bother with updating C++/CLI.

Comment: OK - thanks. I'll investigate further. For now i've got this working by hard coding each delegate_type. Will let you know if I work out why that was needed!

Comment: @IllidanS4 - Looks like a compiler bug on my end - guessing you are using newer than VS 2015?

Comment: Yeah, VS 2017. They might have patched the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ECMA-372:

> A program that attempts to take the address of a member function of a non-native class in any context other
>   than in the creation of a delegate, is ill-formed. There is no pointer-to-member representation for members of
>   non-native classes.

This, unfortunately, means, that `&Class::Function` is invalid. In my opinion, this restriction is useless, because the [`ldftn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldftn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instruction in CIL is precisely what this is nontheless compiled to in a delegate construction. A "pointer to managed function" type is missing in C++/CLI sadly, although it clearly exists in CIL.

So no, a method must be passed around contained in a delegate. However, if you are open to macros, you can use something like this:

```
#define CreateTask(obj, func, arg) TaskRunner::Create(gcnew System::Action<decltype(arg)>(obj, func), arg)
```

Edit: It's a bit tricky to make this also work for the *Func* case, but it works too with some templating:

```
template <class Ret, class... Args>
struct delegate_type
{
    using type = System::Func<Args..., Ret>;
};

template <class... Args>
struct delegate_type<void, Args...>
{
    using type = System::Action<Args...>;
};

#define CreateTask(obj, func, arg) TaskRunner::Create(gcnew delegate_type<decltype(obj->func(arg)), decltype(arg)>::type(obj, &func), arg)
```

Just don't use it with `&Class::Function`, pass `Class::Function` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Thats a shame. Macros aren't as clean but they will get the job done. This is actually a set of functions for an assortment of numbers of arguments / Func as well as action. Would there be any way in a macro to handle the Func case? (i.e. extract the return type to feed into the Func type specifiers)

Comment: @Hector Maybe. I just need to figure out how to obtain the return type of a managed function.

Comment: I've spent the last 30 minutes attempting to do so myself with no luck. If you do work it out it would be appreciated - my inner perfectionist is not happy about having to create the delegate manually - especially as I can't see a technical reason for this restriction.

Comment: @Hector Turned out taking longer than I expected, but I got this to compile (despite IntelliSense seemingly not liking it). I just hope that you also don't want this to support multiple parameters :-P Theoretically, the `Class` part could also be omitted, but I couldn't work out how to call a static function on a `decltype`.

Comment: Now i'm impressed! So if I wanted to support multiple parameters.. Is that feasible? I'm happy enough writing a generator once I have the basic idea of it. I was hoping the "..." meant the delegate_type would be able to take multiple arguments but "TaskRunner::Create(gcnew TaskRunner::delegate_type<decltype(obj->func(arg0, arg1)), decltype(arg0), decltype(arg1)>::type(obj, &func), arg0, arg1)" fails with 'System::Action': too many generic arguments"

Comment: OK - so adding a hard coded "template <class TArg0, class TArg1> ref struct delegate_type<void, TArg0, TArg1>" works. But Args... didn't. Would you be able to explain why to me / is there a way not requiring a hard coded delegate_type for each option?

Comment: @Hector IntelliSense is deceiving you. Try actually compiling the standard `delegate_type` ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately not - its a compilation error. Even my original code gave intellisense errors!

Comment: Updated the question